# Вектор. Почему элементы удаляются через одного

Tags: c++, вектор

В общем нужно удалить все 0. Но если числа стоят в начале или конце или два рядом, то происходит какая-то чушь. Почему и как исправить ?
  А еще нашел функцию - удаление по значению, но жалуется на значение:

```
int value_to_remove = 0;
v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), value_to_remove), v.end());

int main()
    {
        int n;
        cout << "Введите количество чисел в векторе: "; cin >> n;
        vector<int> v(n);
        cout << "Заполните вектор: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cin >> v[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            if (v[i] == 0) {
                v.erase(v.begin() + i);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            cout << v[i] << " ";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Где жалуется? https://ideone.com/wI89mc Отлично удаляет все нули...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
    if (v[i] == 0) {
        v.erase(v.begin() + i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Почему

Ну вот стоят два нуля на местах `k` и `k+1`. Ноль на месте `k` удаляется, тогда следующий ноль встаёт на его место. Но уже не проверяется, ведь следующая итерация цикла проверяет `k+1`-й индекс.

> и как исправить ?

Самое простое - обойти вектор от конца к началу.

Comment: да, наверное  лучше идти от конца.

Answer (score 0):

Пример перемещения в конец с последующим удалением   `v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 0), v.end());` в вопросе, не должен приводить к ошибкам, ошибку ищите в другом месте(если она есть), а удаление в цикле можете выполнить например так:

```
int i = 0, sz = v.size();
while (i < sz)
{
    if (v[i]) ++i;
    else {
        v.erase(v.begin() + i);
        --sz;
    }
}
```